# SonarQube 5.2 Upgrade to 5.3 fail to execute DROP INDEX unique_schema_migrations

Tags: sonarqube, upgrade

I've attempted an upgrade on one system running Windows 2008 R2 SP1 and after trying multiple times get the same error.  We've rolled back to 5.2 for now.  The actual error is: **java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fail to execute DROP INDEX unique_schema_migrations ON schema_migrations**

Here is a portion of the log file ending with the error that causes the upgrade to fail:

```
    found an existing binding; you may want to run a clean build.
    WARNING: while creating new bindings for class org.jruby.rack.RackInput,
    found an existing binding; you may want to run a clean build.
    2016.01.14 17:27:41 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.Monitor] Process[web] is up
    2016.01.14 17:28:01 INFO  web[o.s.s.d.m.PlatformDatabaseMigration]          
    Starting DB Migration
    2016.01.14 17:28:02 INFO  web[DbMigration] ==  CreateUserTokens:   migrating ===============================================
    2016.01.14 17:28:02 INFO  web[DbMigration] -- create_table("user_tokens", {})
    2016.01.14 17:28:02 INFO  web[DbMigration]    -> 0.0310s
    2016.01.14 17:28:02 INFO  web[DbMigration]    -> 0 rows
    2016.01.14 17:28:02 INFO  web[DbMigration] -- index_exists?("user_tokens", "token_hash", {:name=>"user_tokens_token_hash"})
    2016.01.14 17:28:02 INFO  web[DbMigration]    -> 0.0310s
    2016.01.14 17:28:02 INFO  web[DbMigration] -- add_index("user_tokens", "token_hash", {:name=>"user_tokens_token_hash", :unique=>true})
    2016.01.14 17:28:02 INFO  web[DbMigration]    -> 0.0160s
    2016.01.14 17:28:02 INFO  web[DbMigration]    -> 0 rows
    2016.01.14 17:28:02 INFO  web[DbMigration] -- index_exists?("user_tokens", ["login", "name"], {:name=>"user_tokens_login_name"})
    2016.01.14 17:28:02 INFO  web[DbMigration]    -> 0.0000s
    2016.01.14 17:28:02 INFO  web[DbMigration] -- add_index("user_tokens", ["login", "name"], {:name=>"user_tokens_login_name", :unique=>true})
    2016.01.14 17:28:02 INFO  web[DbMigration]    -> 0.0000s
    2016.01.14 17:28:02 INFO  web[DbMigration]    -> 0 rows
    2016.01.14 17:28:02 INFO  web[DbMigration] ==  CreateUserTokens: migrated (0.0780s) ======================================
    2016.01.14 17:28:02 INFO  web[DbMigration] 
    2016.01.14 17:28:02 INFO  web[DbMigration] ==  FixSizeOfSnapshotsQualifier: migrating ====================================
    2016.01.14 17:28:02 INFO  web[DbMigration] -- remove_index(:snapshots, {:name=>"snapshots_qualifier"})
    2016.01.14 17:28:02 INFO  web[DbMigration]    -> 0.0160s
    2016.01.14 17:28:02 INFO  web[DbMigration]    -> 0 rows
    2016.01.14 17:28:02 INFO  web[DbMigration] -- change_column("snapshots", "qualifier", :string, {:limit=>10, :null=>true})
    2016.01.14 17:28:02 INFO  web[DbMigration]    -> 0.0000s
    2016.01.14 17:28:02 INFO  web[DbMigration] -- index_exists?(:snapshots, :qualifier, {:name=>"snapshots_qualifier"})
    2016.01.14 17:28:02 INFO  web[DbMigration]    -> 0.0000s
    2016.01.14 17:28:02 INFO  web[DbMigration] -- add_index(:snapshots, :qualifier, {:name=>"snapshots_qualifier"})
    2016.01.14 17:28:02 INFO  web[DbMigration]    -> 0.2500s
    2016.01.14 17:28:02 INFO  web[DbMigration]    -> 0 rows
    2016.01.14 17:28:02 INFO  web[DbMigration] ==  FixSizeOfSnapshotsQualifier: migrated (0.2810s) ===========================
    2016.01.14 17:28:02 INFO  web[DbMigration] 
    2016.01.14 17:28:02 INFO  web[DbMigration] ==  FixMssqlCollation: migrating ==============================================
    2016.01.14 17:28:02 INFO  web[o.s.d.v.v.FixMsSqlCollation] Updating columns from table characteristics
    2016.01.14 17:28:02 INFO  web[o.s.d.v.v.FixMsSqlCollation] Updating columns from table rules_parameters
    2016.01.14 17:28:02 INFO  web[o.s.d.v.v.FixMsSqlCollation] Updating columns from table rules_profiles
    2016.01.14 17:28:02 INFO  web[o.s.d.v.v.FixMsSqlCollation] Updating columns from table project_qprofiles
    2016.01.14 17:28:02 INFO  web[o.s.d.v.v.FixMsSqlCollation] Updating columns from table widgets
    2016.01.14 17:28:02 INFO  web[o.s.d.v.v.FixMsSqlCollation] Updating columns from table groups
    2016.01.14 17:28:02 INFO  web[o.s.d.v.v.FixMsSqlCollation] Updating columns from table snapshots
    2016.01.14 17:28:02 INFO  web[o.s.d.v.v.FixMsSqlCollation] Updating columns from table schema_migrations
    2016.01.14 17:28:02 ERROR web[o.s.s.d.m.DatabaseMigrator] Fail to execute database migration: org.sonar.db.version.v53.FixMsSqlCollation
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fail to execute DROP INDEX unique_schema_migrations ON schema_migrations
at org.sonar.db.version.DdlChange$Context.execute(DdlChange.java:70) ~[sonar-db-5.3.jar:na]
```

Thanks in advance,
Wes MacDonald

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look like index is missing in the 5.2 version. To Fix the issue create the index on 5.2 database for the table schema_migrations. Here is the command

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX unique_schema_migrations ON dbo.schema_migrations(version);

I did the migration from 5.2 to 5.3 after this fix